# Loading list of Vue.components as an exported array to be used in app.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am on Laravel 8 and am using vue.js v2.6. I am attempting to move all of my `Vue.component()` declarations out of app.js and declare them in their own file so `app.js` is less cluttered. So in my project I created a new file `js/vueComponents.js` and in there I paste all of my vue component declarations. Then in `app.js` I am attempting to import and `Vue.use(require())` but I am getting these errors in the console:

```
app.js:4301 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components...
```

I am a bit new to importing js files as modules etc...am I not doing this correctly?

vueComponents.js

```
import * as Vue from 'vue'

export let vueFiles = [
        Vue.component('users-page', require('./components/users-page.vue').default),
        Vue.component('admin-page', require('./components/admin-page.vue').default),
        ...20 more components...
    ];
```

app.js

```
import { vueFiles } from './vueComponents.js';
Vue.use(vueFiles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vueComponents.js

```
// no need to import Vue.
// Just do this... (no array)
Vue.component('users-page', require('./components/users-page.vue'));
Vue.component('admin-page', require('./components/admin-page.vue'));
```

app.js

```
require("./vueComponents.js") // give the correct path.
```